# Mapping row values of one table to column name of another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have table which keeps track of updates on 15 tables called 'tracking_table'.
As i wanted only one table for all 15 tables i kept 10 columns in 'tracking_table' which is max values of no of cols in all 15 tables.

Now from tracking_table i'm able to get the latest updates done on particular column of particular table in following structure.

```
p_key_no    col_name    value               table
__________________________________________________________________
1       ALTEMAIL    abc@gmail.com           emp_info
1       PASSWORD    AA321                   emp_info
2       ALTEMAIL    xyz@gmail.com           emp_info
2       EMAIL       pqr@yahoo.com           emp_info
2       PASSWORD    SB12321                 emp_info
```

this keep track of name of table, name of column, primary key value of particular row and its changed value.

And emp_info table is as shown below:

```
PKEY    EMAIL           FULLNAME    PASSWORD    TIME_STAMP                  ALTEMAIL        
1       a123@xyz.com    xyz1        AA123       2013-04-05 13:24:49.650     aaa@gmail.com       
2       b123@xyz.com    xyz2        BB123       2013-04-05 13:24:49.650     bbb@gmail.com       
3       c123@xyz.com    xyz3        CC123       2013-04-05 13:24:49.650     ccc@gmail.com
```

i want to show emp_info table with updated values of particular column only.

So please help me to map row values to original table column name and value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done several different ways, one way is by first pivoting the `tracking_table` which will convert the values from rows into columns and then joining on your `emp_info` table.

The pivot code will be similar to the following:

```
select p_key_no, ALTEMAIL, PASSWORD, EMAIL
from tracking_table
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col_name in (ALTEMAIL, PASSWORD, EMAIL)
) p
where [table] ='emp_info'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00454/5). This get the data in rows that can be used for data comparison with the `emp_info` table.  The final code will be similar to:

```
;with cte as
(
  select p_key_no, ALTEMAIL, PASSWORD, EMAIL
  from tracking_table
  pivot
  (
    max(value)
    for col_name in (ALTEMAIL, PASSWORD, EMAIL)
  ) p
  where [table] ='emp_info'
)
select e.pkey,
  coalesce(c.email, e.email) email,
  e.fullname,
  coalesce(c.password, e.password) password,
  time_stamp,
  coalesce(c.altemail, e.altemail) altemail
from emp_info e
left join cte c
  on e.pkey = c.p_key_no;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00454/4). This gives a final result:

```
| PKEY |         EMAIL | FULLNAME | PASSWORD |          TIME_STAMP |      ALTEMAIL |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1 |  a123@xyz.com |     xyz1 |    AA321 | 2013-04-05 13:24:49 | abc@gmail.com |
|    2 | pqr@yahoo.com |     xyz2 |  SB12321 | 2013-04-05 13:24:49 | xyz@gmail.com |
|    3 |  c123@xyz.com |     xyz3 |    CC123 | 2013-04-05 13:24:49 | ccc@gmail.com |
```

The pivot could also be written using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select p_key_no, 
  max(case when col_name = 'ALTEMAIL' then value end) ALTEMAIL,
  max(case when col_name = 'PASSWORD' then value end) PASSWORD,
  max(case when col_name = 'EMAIL' then value end) EMAIL 
from tracking_table
where [table] ='emp_info'
group by p_key_no
```

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet but i dont want to make it hard coded bcoz there are 15 tables with different number of columns with different names..

Comment: @Rohit Are you going to be passing in the table name each time? Since you are storing 15 different tables in the same update table it will be incredibly difficult and you will have to use a dynamic SQL solution. Let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: yes i'm going to convert total solution to SP and gonna pass table name as parameter.. Thanks :)